# python table app that cycles itself

Tags: python, django

I am kinda new to python programming and i would need some help with a project i am trying to accomplish.

So, i managed to scrape some data i needed from a website and store them to csv files. What i want to do now is to project/print them on a table/tables.

But, there are some rules : 
1) i want the table to be like 25 rows per page (1 data/row) and fill the whole screen. if the data i want to project/print exceed 25 rows, a new page will be created and store the next data and so on and so on. The data i am fetching are not specific every time. Sometimes could be like 10 data = 1 page/table with 10 rows, an other time could be like 70 data = 3 pages/tables (with 25 + 25 + 20 rows).
2) Then i want to cycle through pages/tables automatically

Is this even possible to be made with python ? 
Also, is this possible to be made as an app or it would be easier to be made as a website app though Django for example ?

I would love to point me to some direction guys, i am really lost on that matter.
I would appreciate to get every help i can get.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are going to need to use something called `pagination`. This is definitely supported in Django, but isn't inherently easy to provide you a complete working answer to. Instead, here is an example to get you started, and maybe you can formulate more questions from here:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html